# how to make visual studio output window editable

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

I am using visual studio for compiling java programs via external tool.Visual studio output window shows the results.But i cannot input any data through output window like in cmd.How to make output window editable? If i attempt to give an input, It shows read-only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say it's read-only **by design**. You can't change it, you need to fix the tool.

Comment: are there any other ideas for running java?                                                                  Thank you

Comment: This is not inherently Java-related. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Perhaps it's possible via command line switches, or input redirection?